# Get Audit information of user connected as sys

Tags: oracle12c, audit, oracle19c, audit-logging, audit-trail

all the dbas access via arcos and login as common oracle user in putty session and log into database as sys as sysdba.

scenario, user A logs into a putty session as common oracle user via ARCOS, then logs into the database as sys as sysdba.

My question is can I set audit for sys user if they are manipulating a table, can i get information that user 'A' connected through putty as oracle user into the database and executed some query?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SYS operations can be audited. Depending on whether you are using tradition or unified auditing in your database, check the following documentation links:

- **Traditional Auditing:** https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/AUDIT_SYS_OPERATIONS.html#GUID-58176267-238C-40B5-B1F2-BB8BB9518950
- **Unified Auditing:** https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/configuring-audit-policies.html#GUID-D352B575-2EA9-451D-9170-FD9298993DEF